# How to pass values between UserControls?

Tags: c#, user-controls

So i've a Form1 with three UserControl's as UC1,UC2 & UC3. Form1 contains a Button, UC1 and UC3. Both UC1 & UC3 are initially hidden when the application runs and the Form1 button click event makes the UC1 visible. UC1 contains a panel and inside the UC1 load event I'm adding UC2 into the panel through panel.Controls.Add() method at application run time. UC2 contains a Button and the click event of this button makes UC3 visible in Form1. UC3 contain a textbox. Now when I click the **UC2 Button**, I want it to pass a string value to **UC3 textbox**. How do I do that? or generally I need a simple solution to send values from one UserControl to another UserControl.

[image: This is the Form1 with Button]

[image: This is when Form1 Button click makes UC1 visible and also UC2 get added at run time]

[image: This is when UC3 gets visible with a textbox after button click event from UC2]

Here is all my code...

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace Problem
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        uC11.u3Visible += UC11_u3Visible;// Event came from UC1
     }

     private void UC11_u3Visible(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        uC31.Visible = true;
        uC11.Visible = false;
     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        uC11.Visible = true;
     }
  }
}
```

**UC1.cs**

```
namespace Problem
{
  public partial class UC1 : UserControl
  {
      public event EventHandler u3Visible;//Declaring a public event
      public UC1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void UC1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          UC2 xy = new UC2();
          xy.Name = "UsrCntrl2";
          xy.Location = new Point(18, panel1.Controls.Count * 73);
          panel1.Controls.Add(xy);// Adding UC2 in UC1
          xy.open += Xy_open;// UC2 button click event
      }

      private void Xy_open(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          EventHandler handler = u3Visible;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new EventArgs());// Creating another event to make UC3 visible 
              //upon button click from UC2.
          }
      }
   }
}
```

**UC2.cs**

```
namespace Problem
{
   public partial class UC2 : UserControl
 {

    public event EventHandler open;//Declaring a public event
    public UC2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = open;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs());// Button click sending this event
        }
        string text = "Hello There!";// "I want this string to pass into UC3 textbox"
        var ass = new UC3(text);


    }
  }
}
```

**UC3.cs**

```
namespace Problem
{
   public partial class UC3 : UserControl
{
    public UC3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public UC3(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TB.Text = text;// why textbox not showing this value?
        MessageBox.Show(text);// while this MessageBox showing it!
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @vasily.sib okay! I tried your way public UC3(string text) : this(), but still textbox not showing the value

Comment: sorry, I missed that you already call for `InitializeComponent()` in your constructor

Comment: ohh! okay haha, thanks for your comment anyway. I'm stuck with this problem for hours now and my brain stopped working. I really believe there will be a pretty simple solution for this, just don't know how. Now just hoping someone finds me that simple solution :) !

Comment: You are creating a new instance of UC3 and not making it visible, it is not the UC3 that you added to your designer. Try adding a property to your UC3 and have it change the text in your TextBox, there is no need to create another UC3.

Comment: @MarkHall, thank you for your comment. you are right that `var ass = new UC3(text);` creating a new instance of UC3 and passing the string to it and it's not showing because it's a different instance that i've added in Form1. I have managed to find a solution for this problem and now it's working :)

Comment: Very good, glad you got it working.